# One of the assembly gets deleted from my solution everytime I build

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I am using VS2012 and I am seeing weird problem. I added a new project into my solution and that project was working all fine until now.

Now, Everytime I build/re-build the solution, i am seeing reference errors from different projects which are using that particular reference. I checked the bin/debug folder and assembly is not there.

Surprisingly enough, when I build that particular project by it self, it builds successfully and produces the assembly into bin/debug folder.

Now, it works when built alone but does not work when build in solution. And when I build entire solution, something causes the .dll file to be deleted somehow to cause all the references to break.

I have done following things so far:

1. Made sure this project is second one to be built in entire solution
2. Went through all the projects which I are depending on this project and added the dependency manually.

Any ideas on how can I solve this issue?

Comment: Are you using an assembly reference to the output of that project or project references within the solution? The recommended approach is the latter (project references) when both projects are in the same solution. Is it possible one of the projects has a post-build event that is moving/deleting the assembly?

Comment: Can you explain in little detail? I may be making the mistake that you suggested but I did not get it properly...

Comment: I just browsed to the bin/debug folder of my new project and added it as a reference wherever required...

Comment: Thank you so much. I changed the reference from physical assembly to the project reference in project tab and it is working now. Thank you so much. I think if you put the explanation in little more detail as an answer so that it can help the readers and I can mark yours as an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the referencing project and the referenced project are both in the same Visual Studio solution then it is generally considered a best practice to use project references rather than assembly references. This ensures that build dependency orders are maintained automatically and helps prevent you from accidentally creating circular references.

Assembly references should only be used when you cannot add the project that created the assembly to your solution. When you do use assembly references (which I don't recommend in this case) you should put the assemblies into a common folder outside of your bin\debug folder structure to ensure you don't accidentally delete the file when, for example, you do a Clean operation.